# How to make a shell script to print last five days in regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sh

For example I want the script to print like this:

if today date is 02/01/2015 then I need the following dates, but they need to be formatted in regular expression:

29/12/2014
30/12/2014
31/12/2014
01/01/2015
02/01/2015

I need some thing like this [d-d]/[m-m]/[y-y]

This is what I tried but not what I wanted!

```
echo [`date -d '5 day ago' +%m`-`date -d '0 day ago' +%m`]/[`date -d '5 day ago' +%d`-`date -d '0 day ago' +%d`]/[`date -d '5 day ago' +%y`-`date -d '0 day ago' +%y`]


[31-02]/[12-01]/[14-15]
```

Could you please let me know how I could get this done?

Comment: **they need to be formatted in regular expression** why is that?

Comment: `[31-02]` is not a regular expression for the strings `31`, `01`, and `02` and similarly for your other "ranges".

Comment: @anubhava, I think he means **"show me a regular expression to match the 5 previous days"**. For example, the regex to match the 5 previous days on '15/03/2014' would be `1[0-4]/03/2014`. You easily can see the problem arising when any of those previous days are in a different month or in a different year.

Comment: kidding? why people keep asking regex to solve the mission impossible? i am looking forward to reading the post asking how to do arithmetics in regex.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input. @Jdamian - Thank you for explaining my issue very well. You understood correctly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very quick and dirty way to get the regex based on user1666959's answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

monthExp=""
dayExp=""
yearExp=""

div=""
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
    read month day year < <(date --date="2015/01/02 -${i} day" "+%m %d %Y")
    echo $month $day $year
    monthExp="${monthExp}${div}$month"
    dayExp="${dayExp}${div}$day"
    yearExp="${yearExp}${div}$year"
    div="|"
done

echo "Step 1"
echo $monthExp
echo $dayExp
echo $yearExp
echo

regex="$monthExp\/$dayExp\/$yearExp"

echo "Step 2"
echo $regex
echo

echo "Check"
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
    date=$(date --date="2015/01/02 -${i} day" "+%m/%d/%Y")
    if [[ "$date" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "$date matches"
    else
        echo "$date DOES NOT MATCH"
    fi
done
```

And the test output:

```
01 01 2015
12 31 2014
12 30 2014
12 29 2014
12 28 2014

Step 1
01|12|12|12|12
01|31|30|29|28
2015|2014|2014|2014|2014

Step 2
01|12|12|12|12\/01|31|30|29|28\/2015|2014|2014|2014|2014

Check
01/01/2015 matches
12/31/2014 matches
12/30/2014 matches
12/29/2014 matches
12/28/2014 matches
```

Re-arrange as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question ('For example I want the script to print like this'):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do date --date="+${i} day" ; done
```

or

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do date --date="2015/04/21 +${i} day" ; done
```

will do it from a given date. Of course, you can also change what format the date is printed by '+' at the end.

Comment: Thank you user1666959 for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This results in an egrep usable regexp

```
{
    re=''
    for repart in $({ echo '.header off '; echo "select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', 'now', '-"{5,4,3,2,1}" days');"; } | sqlite3); do
        re="$re|$repart"
    done
    re="(${re:1})"
    echo "$re"
}
```

result

```
(15/11/2014|16/11/2014|17/11/2014|18/11/2014|19/11/2014)
```

If you want to minify a regexp, please have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~dland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm